# Image blurred when copied from canvas to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas with an image and lines, that I want to make reponsive. Initially I was redrawing the image, but it was flickering, so I found someone's solution to copy canvas to temporary canvas and then back. But when doing so, the image quality becomes extremely low and blurred. Any ways to get the initial image quality?

```
function resize() {         
    var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    tempCanvas.width = ctx.canvas.width;
    tempCanvas.height = ctx.canvas.height;
    var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tempContext.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0, tempCanvas.width, tempCanvas.height);       
    canvas.width = tempCanvas.width
    canvas.height = 600 * canvas.width / 1400;  
    ctx.drawImage(tempContext.canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
function drawLines(canvas, context){
    var width = canvas.width;
    var offset = 100 * canvas.height / 600;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(width, 0);
    context.lineTo(width, offset);
    context.fill();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, canvas.height - offset);
    context.lineTo(width, canvas.height);
    context.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
    context.fill();
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("new-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth; 
canvas.height = 600 * window.innerWidth / 1400;
var img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById("canvas").style.height = canvas.height;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';   
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    drawLines( canvas, ctx );   
};
img.src = 'image.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to redraw from the original image. You can not invent data that has been discarded.

But note that your flickering issue was probably caused by the fact the resize event may fire at higher frequency than your screen refresh rate.
So you ended up resetting the whole context + redrawing it all + rescaling an image many times in a single frame.

Thus it is very well possible that you experience flicker indeed.

To avoid this, throttle your event with *requestAnimationFrame* so that you handle the event only once per frame.

```js
function throttle(callback) {
  if (typeof callback !== 'function')
    throw new TypeError('A callback function must be passed');
  var active = false; // a simple flag
  var evt; // to keep track of the last event
  function handler() { // fired only when screen has refreshed
    active = false; // release our flag 
    callback(evt);
  }
  return function handleEvent(e) { // the actual event handler
    evt = e; // save our event at each call
    if (!active) { // only if we weren't already doing it
      active = true; // raise the flag
      requestAnimationFrame(handler); // wait for next screen refresh
    }
  };
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';
img.onload = start;

const grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(50, 50, 0, 50, 50, 50);
grad.addColorStop(0.2, 'gold');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'transparent');
const bokeh = [];
for(let i=0; i<30; i++) {
  bokeh.push({
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
    s: Math.random()
  });
}



function start() {
  // our resize handler will fire only once per frame
  window.onresize = throttle(resizeHandler);
  resizeHandler();
}
function resizeHandler() {
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = img.height* (innerWidth / img.width);
  draw();
}
function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
  bokeh.forEach(function(b) {
    const size = b.s*canvas.width / img.width;
    const x = b.x * canvas.width;
    const y = b.y * canvas.height;
    ctx.setTransform(size, 0, 0, size, x, y);
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,100, 100);
  });
}
```

```css
body{margin:0}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**But beware,** while such throttling works well for static content, if you are running an animation loop, it will end up actually causing more flicker.

Indeed, since animation loop *should* be powered by *requestAnimationFrame¨, and the next tick is scheduled since the last frame, your animation code will run before our throttled event handler.
This means that when the browser will have ended the execution of all stacked rAF callbacks, the last action will be our resize handler, and it will paint an empty canvas.

So in case of animated content, you need to handle this case from your animation loop directly.
You set your resize handler to simply raise a flag letting know the main loop that it should resize the canvas before any other actions. 
If no resize event happened since the last frame, just ignore this update and proceed with the rest of the animation loop.

Like this, you are sure to run your code only when needed, and only once per frame.

```js
// a simple 'size' object
const size = {
  dirty: true,
  update: () => {
    // will get called from the mainLoop, if dirty
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = img.height * (innerWidth / img.width);
    size.dirty = false;
  }
};
// the resize handler only rises the size.dirty flag
window.onresize = e => size.dirty = true;


// the main anim loop, called every frame
function mainLoop() {
  // only if it did change
  if (size.dirty) {
    // resizing the canvas is the first step
    size.update();
  }
  // now we can update our objects
  flakes.forEach((flake) => flake.update());
  // and finally draw
  draw();
  // we are a loop
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
  flakes.forEach((flake) => flake.draw());
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image();
const grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(50, 50, 0, 50, 50, 50);
grad.addColorStop(0.2, 'gold');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'transparent');

class Flake {
  constructor() {
    this.x = Math.random();
    this.y = Math.random();
    this.s = Math.random();
    this.wind = this.weight = this.s * 0.001;
    this.dx = Math.random() * this.s * 0.1;
  }
  update() {
    let dx = this.dx += this.wind;
    this.x += Math.sin(dx * 0.01);
    if (Math.abs(dx) > .1 * this.s) this.wind *= -1;

    this.y += this.weight;
    if (this.y > 1) this.y = ((this.s * 100) / canvas.height) * -1;
  }
  draw() {
    const size = this.s * canvas.width / img.width;
    const y = this.y * canvas.height;
    const rad = size * 50;
    const area = canvas.width + (rad * 2);
    const x = ((this.x * canvas.width) % area) - (rad * 2);

    ctx.setTransform(size, 0, 0, size, x, y);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  }
}
const flakes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  flakes.push(new Flake());
}

img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';
img.onload = mainLoop;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer it helped. As for throttle(), you do it to stop requestAnimationFrame()  after the first iteration? I guess requestAnimationFrame() is running over and over?!

Comment: No, requestAnimationFrame() is called by the original event, and only if the `active` flag is set to *false* (i.e when no other rAF has been done for this frame). No event, no rAF.

Comment: Relatively new to js, so I am a little bit confused. What if I use `window.onresize = () => {
   requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };`

Comment: You will stack multiple calls to `draw` that will all get called consecutively before the next paint. i.e not a great idea ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Last question, why do we use `callback(evt)` if resizeHandler() does not have any parameters?

Comment: Because `throttle` is a generic method I wrote long ago, and that I sometime need the event (e.g useful for wheel events).